# QToolbar behaving weird with QAction and &(ampersand)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

According to the docs the `QAction` uses a single `&` to mark a shortcut mnemonic but when I used it on the `QToolbar` it does not work. Then I tried `&&` which worked and the mnemonic appeared with the shortcut working fine and underline appearing properly.
But according to the docs `&&` is used to show single `&` in the label.

> Failing code

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
#####Custom edited example
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.actionNotification = QAction(self)
        self.actionNotification.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionNotification.setChecked(False)
        self.actionNotification.setEnabled(True)
        self.actionNotification.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionNotification.setVisible(True)
        self.actionNotification.setIconVisibleInMenu(False)
        self.actionNotification.setObjectName("actionNotification")
        self.toolBar = QToolBar(self)
        self.toolBar.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.toolBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.toolBar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionNotification)
        self.actionNotification.setText("&Notification") #the problem lies here
        self.actionNotification.setToolTip(
            QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Click to see new notifications", None,
                                   QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Main()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

> Working code

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys
#####Custom edited example
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.actionNotification = QAction(self)
        self.actionNotification.setCheckable(True)
        self.actionNotification.setChecked(False)
        self.actionNotification.setEnabled(True)
        self.actionNotification.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionNotification.setVisible(True)
        self.actionNotification.setIconVisibleInMenu(False)
        self.actionNotification.setObjectName("actionNotification")
        self.toolBar = QToolBar(self)
        self.toolBar.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.toolBar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.toolBar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionNotification)
        self.actionNotification.setText("&&Notification") #this works
        self.actionNotification.setToolTip(
            QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Click to see new notifications", None,
                                   QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Main()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

A quick question on IRC(people there were really helpful) confirmed me that it was a qt issue as this was the same issue in pyqt4 and that `QAction` works fine with `QMenu` and the problem exists only for `QToolBar`

I thought about asking this question here to have an extended discussion and if possible to learn why it behaves so.

**tl;dr**:what should be done about this weird behaviour of `QToolBar`? I would like to know why it behaves so.

Any help or suggestion would be really great

**system**: Debian,python2.7, PySide-1.1

Comment: Its neither pyqt nor Qt4 specific - it is also reproduceable in C++ using Qt 5.3. Most likely, its a bug - something similar has been reported earlier (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2229), but closed as "out of scope". If you want to use the same `QAction` in a menubar **and** in a toolbar, probably all you can do is to use separate `QAction`s for the toolbar and the menu bar, and to avoid code duplication just call the `trigger()` slot of the other `QAction` in one of both.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for that info!!

Answer (score 0):

To work around this bug, you can call `QAction.setIconText("&Foo")` and the mnemonic will be respected.